# Commandline arguments in docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

The `mysql` image for docker allows configuration parameters when running the container.

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

How is this achievable with docker-compose?
I've tried doing `-command` but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Considering [mysql image Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/d7e71447ff3ad3c579ac3cca8c0dc090d11d4baf/5.7/Dockerfile) has a `CMD` set to `mysqld`, you would need to include it to your [`docker-compose.yml` v2 `command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command):

```
command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Or try:

```
command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8mb4, --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci]
```

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm! Thanks alot

Comment: Thanks @VonC ! I can confirm that it worked with docker-compose v3 too. Get it work the the `--general-log` of MySQL (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54404114/960623).