# Enable logging in docker mysql container

Tags: mysql, logging, docker

I'm trying to get familiar with the docker ecosystem and tried to setup a mysql database container. With `docker-compose` this looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.33@sha256:31ad2efd094a1336ef1f8efaf40b88a5019778e7d9b8a8579a4f95a6be88eaba
    volumes:
      - "./db/data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./db/log:/var/log/mysql"
      - "./db/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
    restart: "yes"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpw
```

My conf directory contains one file:

```
[mysqld]
log_error       =/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log     =1
slow_query_log  =1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log
long_query_time =2
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
```

Unfortunately I don't get any log files that way. The setup itself is correct and the cnf file is used. After connecting to the container and creating the 3 files, `chown` them to `mysql` and restarting the container, the logging is working as expected.

I'm pretty sure that this is a common scenario, and my current way to get it running seems really stupid. **What is the correct way to do it?**

I could improve my approach by moving all this stuff in a Dockerfile, but this still seem strange to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> After connecting to the container and creating the 3 files, chown them to mysql and restarting the container, the logging is working as expected.

That points to a host volume permission issue. When you map from a container to the host, no mappings are made on user id's, and the name attached to the uid inside the container may be very different from outside. You need to initialize the directory permissions with something the container user can write to. One simple method is to create a group that has access to write to the files on both the host and container, and then add the various users to this group on both your image and host OS. Another option is to use a named filesystem that you don't access directly from your host and initialize it with the image's directory permissions.

---

Edit: An example of a named volume with your docker-compose.yml is as simple as:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  mysql-log:
    driver: local
  mysql-conf:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.33
    volumes:
      - "mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "mysql-log:/var/log/mysql"
      - "mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpw
```

Note that I also removed the sha256 from your image name, this reference would block you from being able to pull patched versions of the image. I also prefer the "unless-stopped" restart policy so that Docker does expected things on a reboot.

Comment: The documentation of names volumes seems to be partially outdated and incomplete. Where is this data stored? Am I right, that I still need to know the uid and gid of the mysql container, to start the volume with this rights?

Comment: Named volumes are stored in internal Docker folders (/var/lib/docker typically). If you try to access them there, you create the same problem that you have with host volumes. Rather, you should only access them via Docker containers. You can mount the same volume in multiple containers, so you can have a container to do things like updates and backups.

Comment: I will stay with my sha, to make sure that I test and deploy the same version, but `unless-stopped` is a good hint.

Comment: For versioning between test/stage/prod, I'd recommend using a private registry server and tagging your specific images. You can have the same image with multiple tags making something like v5 tagged as test and then tagged as staging very easy to manage. You can pull from Docker Hub, retag or even do a build with your own additions, and then push to your private registry. All test/stage/prod servers would only pull from that private registry.

Comment: I guess the best practice for my conf directory is a new own image based on mysql anyway, otherwise I would have to prefill the volume somehow?

Comment: Pre-filling a volume is as easy as `tar -cC $(pwd)/conf . | docker run --rm -it -v mysql-conf:/target busybox tar -xC /target`, lots of other similar options. In the compose file, add `external: true` to that volume definition so it doesn't prepend a project name and expects the volume to already exist ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external)).

Answer (score 29):

I was looking for the exact same thing, and now, there is a better way to do it.

The [docker mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) writes:

> Many configuration options can be passed as flags to `mysqld`. This will
> give you the flexibility to customize the container without needing a
> `cnf` file. For example, if you want to change the default encoding and
> collation for all tables to use UTF-8 (`utf8mb4`) just run the
> following:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
> ```

In a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) world, one could pass these arguments through the ["command"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) section of the service:

```
command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

In my use case, I just wanted to turn on the logs and specify the path to the log file:

```
 command: mysqld --general-log=1 --general-log-file=/var/lib/mysql/general-log.log
```

With the adequate volumes (e.g. `- ./logs/mysql.log:/var/lib/mysql/general-log.log`), it becomes easy to reach them.

This is pretty straight forward and avoid dealing with a local configuration. It will work with any [MySQL Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/tags) and will keep the `my.cnf` as shipped by the image.

Edit: change path from `/var/log/mysql/` to `/var/lib/mysql/` to ensure a MySQL writable folder.

Comment: --general_log_file  but not --general-log-file

Comment: @Alex it is `--general-log-file` because it is a command line argument, not a server variable. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file and "command line format".

Comment: This worked for me, but remember to `touch ./logs/mysql.log` before. Otherwise the Docker engine will end up creating this as a directory; at least this is what happened on my machine.

Answer (score 10):

I needed to temporarily enable logging due to a weird PDO binding issue and I wanted to see the actual query being executed. This question was the top search result and I wasn't satisfied with any of the answers. Assuming you already have volumes setup for the container, I got it working the following way:

1. Run the following queries on the database:

```
SET global general_log = on;
SET global general_log_file='/var/log/mysql/mysql.log';
SET global log_output = 'file';
```

2. Get the container ID using `docker ps`.
3. Run `docker exec -it <id> /usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`
4. Run the following query once you're done: `SET global general_log = off;`

If you're having problems setting the `general_log_file` variable, you probably need to `/bin/bash` into the container then manually create the log file with the correct permissions.

Comment: Error Code: 1231. Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the value of '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log'

Comment: @MichaelPaccione You might need to manually create the file. You can `/bin/bash` into the container to do that. I'm not sure what changed since I originally gave my answer as I don't remember needing to do that.

Comment: You will be needing SUPER privilege(s) for these operations.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [ponsfrilus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54404114/4884157)
you can do the same from **docker run** command:

```
docker run --name some-mysql --restart always -v //d/MySqlDockerData:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --log_error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql_error.log --general_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.log --general_log=1 --slow_query_log=1 --slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql_slow.log --long_query_time=2 --log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
```