# How to connect spring-boot and mysql using docker?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I tried to make some rest API using spring-boot and MySQL.
And I finished it in my eclipse environment.
The next step is to create a docker image.
However, when I run the MySQL server and my rest API in docker, it gives me a connection refused error.

I found other basic spring-boot and MySQL tutorials. But I can't solve this problem.

This is mysql setting of spring-boot project.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

#spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=example,dc=org

#spring.ldap.base=dc=example,dc=org
#spring.ldap.password=admin
#spring.ldap.username=cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
#spring.ldap.urls=ldap://localhost:389

##Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#Open session in View
#spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate.ddl-auto=update
```

This is command to run mysql in the docker.

```
docker urn -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --name mysql mysql
```

This is my docker file to make docker image for rest API.

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/userManageWithRest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is error message.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
        ... 59 common frames omitted
```

I already tried to modify `spring.datasource.url` to `jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/users?...`.
How can I solve this problem?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your MySQL database and Spring Boot app are running in a separate Docker container, access `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` within a Docker container isn't referring to the `localhost` of your host machine.

I would suggest to use `docker-compose` to link the Spring Boot application to your MySQL container and make it accessible via `mysql` as hostname as you have already tried it (`jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/users?...`):

```
version: "3"  
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - "mysql"
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Save this in the folder where your Spring Boot `Dockerfile` is located as `docker-compose.yml` and the run `docker-compose build && docker-compose run`.

With the `links` attribute to give access to your MySQL container via the container name and as they are sharing the same Docker network, the `mysql` hostname is resolved correctly

Comment: It occurs same error.. (`Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`, `Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
backend_1  |
backend_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`)

Comment: You need to change your datasource url to SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL = jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/users?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=trueuseLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is a bit old, I believe this explanation might be useful.

The reason for your issue is that you can [control the order of service startup](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) and shutdown with the `depends_on` option. Compose always starts and stops containers in dependency order, where dependencies are determined by depends_on, links...

However, for startup Compose does not wait **until a container is “ready”** (whatever that means for your particular application) - only until it’s running.

That may cause some issues, e.g. your spring-boot app starts very fast and tries to connect to MySQL, but even though MySQL container has started - MySQL inside is not ready to accept connections yet.

There are some workarounds for this. If you are interested in them, you might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235312/docker-compose-getting-mysql-db-fully-started-before-flask-app-starts).