# How to init MySql Database in Docker Compose

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, init

**Scenario:**
I developed a microservice in Spring which uses a mysql 8 database.
This db has to be initalized (create a Database, some tables and data).
On my host machine I initialized the database with data.sql and schema.sql script.
The Problem is, that I have to set:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

for the first execute. This initializes my db the way I want to.
For future runs I have to comment this command. Very ugly soltion but I could not find a better one and I got no reponse right now to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271100/spring-boot-2-initialize-databases-and-tables-only-once).
I thought for testing it is ok but I definetly have to improve that.
Currently I want to run my service with docker by a docker compose.

**Expected:**
This is the docker-compose file. Fairly simple. I'm totally new in the world of docker and so I want to go on step by step.

> ```
> version: '3' 
> services:usermanagement-service:
> build:
>   ./UserManagementService
> restart:
>   on-failure
> ports:
>   - "7778:7778"
> links:
>   - mysqldb
> depends_on:
>   - mysqldb   mysqldb:
> build:
>   ./CustomMySql
> volumes:
>   - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
> restart:
>   on-failure
> environment:
>   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
>   MYSQL_DATABASE: userdb
>   MYSQL_USER: testuser
>   MYSQL_PASSWORD: testuser
> expose:
>   - "3600"
> ```

I was expecting, that my database gets initialized with a user and that in the first run my microservice initializes the db with data.
So before the next start of compose I have to comment the command and rebuild the image. (I know , ugly)

**Problem:**
So besides this ugly solution I run into runtime problems. 
On `docker-compose up` my Microservice is faster than the init of the database. So it tries to call the db what results in en error.
Because of the `restart on failure` the microservice comes up again.
Now it works because the init of the db has finished.

**Solution:**
I searched the www and for it seems like a known problem which might be solved within a `wait-for-it.sh` file. This has to be included with COPY in the Dockerfile.
So I'm no expert but I am searching for a good solution to either:

- init database from within spring und make my service wait till mysql is ready
- or init the database from withn my container via a volume on the first run and of course solve this init problem.

I don't know what is best practice here I and I would be very thankful for some help how to build this up.

Comment: Not a direct solution to your question. But if you use a database migration tool like Flyway then you no need to comment/uncomment the config properties. Based on the current database status Flyway will automatically run the migration scripts.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**For loading your sql files only on the first run:**

You can use the below compose file

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  usermanagement-service:
    build: ./UserManagementService
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "7778:7778"
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-init-files:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: userdb
      MYSQL_USER: testuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testuser
    ports:
      - "3600:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
```

You have to place your `data.sql` and `schema.sql` files under `./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory using `Volumes` [for more info](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

SQL files in this folder will be loaded only if the **DB's data directory is empty (the very first run of db service)**. (i.e) in your case `./mysql-data` folder should be empty

**For your second problem:**

Instead of using `wait-for-it.sh`, you can use `healthcheck` and `service_healthy`. Here `usermanagement-service` will be started once `mysqldb` successfully executes  `["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]` in the specified interval. For more details on healthcheck and depends_on, refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on).

Got `test` command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757250/9025542).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm running into problem with using the depends_on syntax:
services.usermanagement-service.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array
in addition :https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30404
condition is not supportet anymore

Comment: You can set your docker-compose.yml file's version as `2.1`. Like [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30404#issuecomment-285972049)

Comment: But isn't it necessary to have the version fit my docker engine version like [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/)

Comment: It's necessary if you are deploying this in  a swarm, if not it will work. My docker engine version is `18.09.1` and my compose file version is `2.1` and it works like a charm. In the above [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix) it is mentioned that `2.1` version of compose file will work on all the versions of docker engine released after `v1.12.0`.