# docker-compose + spring-boot + mysql = CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker-compose, liquibase

The spring boot app fails with **`liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`** caused by: **`java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-server: Name does not resolve`**

Tried to wait for `mysql` with waiting for condition:`service_healthy` and restart app **on-failure**. No effect.

docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: motorcycle_info
      MYSQL_USER: demo
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: demo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  backend-spring-boot-app:
    container_name: backend-spring-boot-app
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: backend-spring-boot-app:latest
    restart: on-failure
    links:
      - "db:db"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_USER=demo
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=demo
      - DATABASE_NAME=motorcycle_info
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

Dockerfile for backend-spring-boot-app:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

app props:

```
# Datasource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/motorcycle_info?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false # for db container
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

# Hibernate naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

# Liquibase
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/liquibase-changelog.xml

# Application context
server.servlet.context-path=/bearings-info/api
server.port=8090

#Logging
logging.file=log/application.log
logging.level.root=DEBUG
```

exception log:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.pazukdev.backend.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:307) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:302) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-server: Name does not resolve
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

db | 2019-07-31T07:25:18.147239Z 3 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Was googling a lot, but still didn't found solution.

Whats wrong with my docker-compose?

Pay attention on last line in log: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. This is result of service healthcheck with ping. So, that means that db is already running.

**Aditionally:** why access is denied? This healthcheck is the same as in example I had found ( [Docker-compose check if mysql connection is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready) ) and there was no any additional configs neither for db nor for ping command.

Comment: Have you provided datasource driver class? `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: @htshame Given the error mentioned is produced by the MySQL Connector/J driver, it is clear that the driver has been loaded.

Comment: The error mentions `java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-server: Name does not resolve`, but according to your config, the hostname is `db`. The information provided in your question is either not consistent, or you have connection configuration elsewhere that attempts to connect to a host called `mysql-server`.

Comment: Also, given the use use `links "db:database"` in your docker compse file, you need to use the hostname `database` in your spring config, not `db`.

Comment: @htshame No, I'm not. Not dockerized spring boot app work fine without explicitly specified datasource driver class. Already added to app props. But nothing changed: the same exception.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks, fixed `links` to db.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, no, the info is consistent. I have no any db config excepting defined in application.properties. And have no any "mysql-server" explicitly specified anywhere.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have an error with `java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-server: Name does not resolve`, but one mentioning `db` instead of `mysql-server`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Unfortunately I didn’t found solution in suggested jdbc question. Besides, I have no issues with db  & jdbc as it is. My app is working. I have an issue when the app is dockerized -> so, maybe the problem is in my docker config? PS#1: Can you advise where to look for the app tries to connect to db "mysql-server"? I searched for it, but didn't found anything. The app is a simple spring boot app completely configured in application.properties file. Am using liquibase, but I have no any explicit db config there. PS#2: Updated the question. Exception log added.

Comment: Looking at the stracktrace, the problem is somewhere in your use of Liquibase.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel many thanks for your help! The issue is solved. And the problem was really outside of my docker config.The problem was in my .jar file for 'backend-spring-boot-app' service. I forgot to build a new .jar after I changed db service name from 'mysql-service' to 'db'. So, I had .jar file was built with spring.datasource.url in application.properties specified as 'jdbc:mysql://mysql-service:3306'. And because of that the spring boot app service based on an old .jar was trying to connect to 'mysql-service' instead of actual 'db'.