# No ServletContext set. Problem with connection to DB in another container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I have Kotlin pet-project with docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: java -jar ./testapp.jar
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://172.25.1.3:5432/kotlin-app
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=Tolstochok3000
    networks:
      app-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.1.2

  postgres:
    build:
      context: docker/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "kotlin-app"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "Tolstochok3000"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      app-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.25.1.3
    restart: always
networks:
  app-network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.1.0/16
```

I tried docker-compose up, postgres started without problem, but app throw exception: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

When I started application on localhost (without docker), application work correctly with db in docker.

Application dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:jdk17 as builder
WORKDIR /test-kotlin-app
COPY src ./src
COPY build.gradle.kts ./build.gradle.kts
RUN gradle clean build

FROM openjdk:17-alpine as backend
WORKDIR /root
COPY --from=builder /test-kotlin-app/build/libs/* ./app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/root/app"]
```

Application propeties:

```
  #DATABSE SETTINGS
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kotlin-app}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:Tolstochok3000}
  #JPA SETTINGS
  jpa:
    show-sql: 'true'
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

I tried change docker-compose file application.yml (remove variables) and try remove network, but it didn't help

Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
stacktrace:

```
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.023 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Before shutdown stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.029 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2db15f70: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.030 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6d2041d5: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.030 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@22daa83a: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.030 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3599b284: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.030 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@42f55775: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.030 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@54a28df5: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.030 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@5668d8b3: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.030 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@2e9d5d68: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.031 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@46bbe931: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.031 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6b60936: (connection evicted)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.032 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.032 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | 08:01:35.035 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/W
ebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at ru.rsu.app.KotlinAppApplicationKt.main(KotlinAppApplication.kt:13)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; ne
sted exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   ... 18 common frames omitted
test_kotlin_app-app-1       | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:591)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
test_kotlin_app-app-1       |   ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: May be link on projcet can help:
https://github.com/NikRomanov3000/test-kotlin-pet-app

Comment: unrelated but changing `jdbc:postgresql://172.25.1.3:5432/kotlin-app` to `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/kotlin-app` and removing all that networking stuff would rule out some number of configuration errors.

Comment: I think there's insufficient information here to help.  You've provided neither the full stack trace nor the `Dockerfile` from the springboot project, therefore it may not be possible to assist.

Comment: @Colton I tried remove all network block and change jdbc:postgresql://172.25.1.3:5432/kotlin-app to jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/kotlin-app but it didn't help.

Comment: @Colton Also thank you for the comment. I added stacktrace and app dockerfile to description

Answer (score 1):

I resolve problem, when fixed build section in build.gradle.kts file. Remove block tasks.withType and add build section with default spring boot builder:

```
tasks.named<org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar>("bootJar") {
mainClass.set("con.example.app.KotlinAppApplicationKt")
archiveBaseName.set("testapp")
archiveFileName.set("testapp.jar") }
```

Comment: This solution resolves same propblem for me. But I use just tasks.named("bootJar"), otherwise i get error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your DB container is not yet ready when the app is initialized. You may want to implement some waiting mechanism [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y/41854997#41854997) or like some of [the solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890682/docker-compose-cannot-wait-for-mysql-database).

Comment: I tried add condition :

    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy

But it doesn't work. Same error: No ServletContext set