# Connection refused in Docker container between database container and java container in docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to start a mysql da and a springboot app.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  sql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: people
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  appointment-service:
    depends_on:
      - sql # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      - DATABASE_HOST=sql
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
      - DATABASE_NAME=people
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
    links:
      - "sql:localhost"
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

This is my application.properties

```
server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=my-secret-pw

url.organizations = https://hr.apografi.gov.gr/api/public/organizations
url.db = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people?serverTimezone=UTC
url.username = root
url.password = my-secret-pw
```

and here I create the jdbi:

```
private Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true", "root", "my-secret-pw");
```

no matter what i tried i could not make the containers talk to each-other inside the docker.
If I start the sql alone, I can see the connection in my host machine (in datagrip).
If I run the java program from container, it sees the database in my host machine.
Even if I run my docker-compose file, both the containers are created and I can access them from my host machine. I know that inside the DockerVM the database exists with the name sql/ I have tried both with sql name and the localhost name (from the links property). But no matter what I tried I was not able to access it from my java program inside the Docker.

Here is the stackTrace

```
docker-compose up --build
Building appointment-service
Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> a3562aa0b991
Step 2/4 : ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 603b2c59103f
Step 3/4 : COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4783d891166c
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24deebb3147a
Successfully built 24deebb3147a
Successfully tagged appointments-service_appointment-service:latest
Starting appointments-service_sql_1 ... done
Starting appointments-service_appointment-service_1 ... done
Attaching to appointments-service_sql_1, appointments-service_appointment-service_1
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11 16:47:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11 16:47:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11 16:47:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:28.258555Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 1
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:28.275621Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:28.641173Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:28.823110Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:28.988711Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:28.989000Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:28.999907Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
sql_1                  | 2020-09-11T16:47:29.056993Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
appointment-service_1  |
appointment-service_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
appointment-service_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
appointment-service_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
appointment-service_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
appointment-service_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
appointment-service_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
appointment-service_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.2.RELEASE)
appointment-service_1  |
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:30.628  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.a.service.ServiceApplication           : Starting ServiceApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 5bbe74d3ddb0 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:30.635  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.a.service.ServiceApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:32.822  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:32.876  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 33ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:34.254  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:34.300  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:34.302  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:34.472  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:34.473  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3697 ms
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:35.055  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:35.100  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
appointment-service_1  | 2020-09-11 16:47:36.338 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
appointment-service_1  |
appointment-service_1  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
appointment-service_1  |
appointment-service_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) [spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.appointments.service.ServiceApplication.main(ServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
appointment-service_1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
appointment-service_1  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
appointment-service_1  |
appointment-service_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    ... 57 common frames omitted
appointment-service_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
appointment-service_1  |    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
appointment-service_1  |    ... 60 common frames omitted
appointment-service_1
```

|

Comment: 1) The links feature in DC is deprecated. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links I don't think you need links here at all. 2) Have you tried connecting with URL `jdbc:mysql://sql:3306/` ? Docker compose should handle the DNS details.

Comment: I have removed the links property and tried just with jdbc:mysql://sql:3306/ . No luck.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the DB container using MySQL Workbench to make sure the db server is really accepting connections?  You mention a db exists with the name "sql/", but based on your compose file the db name should be "people", so it's not clear how you are testing that the DB exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `links:` is [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) and useless in this case - just delete that line.
- `localhost` used inside the java container will point to the container itself. You must use the service name that you gave for your sql container(`sql` in your case). The service name will be resolved to the IP of the SQL container.
- `depends_on:` will make the java containers wait for the SQL containers to **start**, but this does not guarantee that the SQL is up and running, ready to accept connections. The are several ways to solve this problem(wait-for-it, `restart: on-failure`, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757250/13736525) etc.)
- you don't need to specify the `MYSQL_USER: root` nor the `MYSQL_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw` if your intent is to use just the root user.(this has nothing to do with your current problem)

```
version: '3'
services:
  sql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: people
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  appointment-service:
    depends_on:
      - sql # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
    restart: on-failure
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      - DATABASE_HOST=sql
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
      - DATABASE_NAME=people
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

```
server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://sql:3306/people?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=my-secret-pw

url.organizations = https://hr.apografi.gov.gr/api/public/organizations
url.db = jdbc:mysql://sql:3306/people?serverTimezone=UTC
url.username = root
url.password = my-secret-pw
```

```
private Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:mysql://sql:3306/people?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true", "root", "my-secret-pw");
```

Comment: links are deprecated when used as a flag, not for the docker-compose

Comment: After adding the restart: on-failure everything worked. Thank you very much.
I wonder however why they downvoted my question.

Comment: @Filip123go, Glad it worked. Thanks for the feedback. No idea why someone down-voted - I found the question reasonable and had enough info to debug and provide a useful answer, hence you just confirmed this. Don't worry, it's -1/+1(+8) now. Perhaps someone considered the question to be a bit too broad: the obvious fix, to replace 'localhost' with `sql` wasn't the only problem. Hence this fix was not accepted, it is natural to believe that there's not enough info to reproduce this or there are multiple problems(__questions_) in the same post.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` always points to the loopback interface (either `127.0.0.1` or `::1`). You cannot, and should not attempt to, override this.

When using docker-compose, you can user service names as hostnames, so the proper JDBC URL for your database would be:

```
jdbc:mysql://sql:3306/people?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Comment: I have tried with jdbc:mysql://sql:3306/people?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true many times. Din't work... Same error. I just tried again. 
Btw I am running the command docker-compose up  --build each time.

Comment: Did you remove `links:
      - "sql:localhost"` beforehand?

Comment: Yes I did remove the entire line.