# Spring app container cannot communicate with mysql container

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker, maven

Im trying to use docker-compose to run 2 containers of 2 existing images ( SQL image with a database built in already & spring app container containing a jar file ) , but somehow i couldn't manage to make them communicate .these are the screenshots :

[`error-screenshot1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJVnc.png)
[`error-screenshot2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2diIf.png)
[`error-screenshot3`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjtMw.png)
[`error-screenshot4`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Pfd.png)
[`app.properties-prod`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpMgZ.png)
[`docker-compose`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woc8x.png)
[`dockerfile-DB`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6kuM.png)
[`dockerfile-app`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNUMC.png)
[`pomXML`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfLBx.png)
[`pomXml`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u95w2.png)
[`pomXml`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4HJU.png)

i tried upgrading and downgrading the jdk image but i think the problem is not in the jdk , the application runs fine in a seperated container , so i know the problem is with the jdbc version or something , i upgraded the version of the jdbc in the pom.xml i built the jar file again , and same thing again , the projects is using a lot of plugins , lombok , flyway .... i thought maybe some of those tools is blocking the communication ..

Comment: Is it because app tries to talk to mysql even before it is completely up? Can you try adding a healthcheck to mysql and set the depends_on condition accordingly? May be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready can help.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text in your questions. Paste in the text and use the formatting tools to format your post. That makes it a lot easier for people to copy/paste your files if they want to try to reproduce your issue.