# Error: Facing error while running the spring boot 3 application image with MySql 8 image in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Created a spring boot 3 application with Java 17, MySql 8. Wanted to deploy the application on Docker. When tried docker-compose up to use spring boot application with MySql 8 image on docker then it shows some error.
Error stack

```
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.example.demo.BasicApplication.main(BasicApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    ... 24 common frames omitted
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processTableResultSet(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtracto
```

Spring boot application dependency file 
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>basic</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>spring_rest_docker</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

Spring boot application configuration file for database connection
application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basics?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Docker file for configuring spring boot application jar in it.
Dockerfile

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/app/target/spring_rest_docker.jar"]
```

Docker compose file to configuring mysql 8 image with spring boot application image

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - springapimysql-net
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/basics?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    
    volumes:
      - .m2:/var/lib/mysql
      
  mysqldb:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - springapimysql-net
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: basics
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
networks:
  springapimysql-net:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose check if mysql connection is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready)

Comment: Also note that your `Dockerfile` is not optimized: you should use a "multistage build" to minimize the image size, see https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/.  The final stage should use a JRE base image instead of a JDK one.  It could be, for example, `eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine`, or, even smaller, `pnavato/amazoncorretto-jre:17-alpine`.