# Docker compose MySQL connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose

I'm having problem where my service keep getting error from `sql.Ping()` 
But it works just fine when I only do `sql.Open()` without pinging MySQL server

Output:

```
dial tcp 172.19.0.3:3306: connect: connection refused
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  go-app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.1.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password_here
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp_database
      MYSQL_USER: myapp_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: myapp_password
    # ports:
    #   - 13306:13306
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.21.1 as builder 

WORKDIR /app

# Copy go.mod and go.sum
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Fetch dependencies
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix -cgo -o main .

######## Start a new stage from scratch #######
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

# Copy the config and pre-built binary files from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /app/main .

# Command to run the executable
CMD [ "./main" ]
```

main.go:main():

```
func main() {
    // Connect to MySQL
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "myapp_user:myapp_password@tcp(mysql:3306)/myapp_database")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Start HTTP server
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello from Go App!")
    })

    log.Println("Server running on :8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

I tried change the port back and fourth but it seems nothing worked. Is it possibly because I have MySQL installed on host or am I missing something else?

Comment: Remove the ping call

Comment: @Shadow it doesn't change the output of `db.Query()` because I have to actually do something with it

Comment: You need to add a health check to the mysql container and a condition to the `depends_on`.    See [this answer from the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54854239/1726083)  I Iinked .  read up on [`depends_on` in the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#depends_on)