# Difficulties Connecting Dockerized Flask App to MySQL Database

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently facing an issue while attempting to establish a connection between a Flask app and a MySQL database, both dockerized. Initially, I successfully dockerized the MySQL database and connected it to the local Flask app using this `docker-compose.yml` configuration:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
   db:
    image: mysql:8.0.33-debian
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - C:/Databases/mysql_flask_test:/var/lib/mysql
```

The connection in the Flask app was made using:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/people') # Initialize the SQLAlchemy engine

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM people_data", engine)
```

This worked, but the problem was when I tried to dockerize the Flask app. I updated the `docker-compose.yml` to include the Flask app as a service:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
   db:
    image: mysql:8.0.33-debian
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - C:/Databases/mysql_flask_test:/var/lib/mysql

   app:
    build: '.'
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The error I encountered was:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

I adjusted the connection string in the Flask app to use 'db' instead of 'localhost':

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@db:3306/people') # Initialize the SQLAlchemy engine

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM people_data", engine)
```

However, this resulted in a new error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"

Seeking an alternative, I attempted to use **mysql.connector** for the connection:

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='root', password='root', host='db', port="3306", database='people')
print("DB connected with mysql.connector")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('Select * FROM people_data')
people = cursor.fetchall()
connection.close()
```

But encountered the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (111)

I'm aware that services in a `docker-compose.yml` file share the same network by default. Despite changing 'localhost' to 'db' in the connection strings, the connection between the MySQL database and the dockerized Flask app isn't established. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose check if mysql connection is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the services can communicate inside a Docker network and the service name can be used as host name BUT you have to define the network in the docker-compose file.

The network definition is missing from your compose file and this is the reason why your Python App doesn't find the DB service.

**Your `docker-compose.yml` file with networking:**

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
   db:
    image: mysql:8.0.33-debian
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    # If you want to connect to DB only from Python App then you don't need to open any port because
    # the services can communicate via any port in the same Docker network.
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - C:/Databases/mysql_flask_test:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - db_net

   app:
    build: '.'
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - db_net

# Define the network.
networks:
  db_net: {}
```

You can connect to the MySQL DB from your Python App with the following connection string (As you mentioned in your question):

```
ngine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@db:3306/people')
```