# Docker: Delay Spring web app's start-up till a MySQL database is ready

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to run this `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/users_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: pp_user
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pp_user

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: users_db
      MYSQL_USER: pp_user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pp_user
```

Here's the referenced Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven && \
    mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/user-management-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "user-management-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Here are my `application.properties` (it's a Spring web application that uses MySQL):

```
# connection properties
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

# initialization
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:/sql/data.sql
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:/sql/schema.sql

# logging
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

The run is not successful. The database is initialized:

```
user-management-system-db-1   | 2023-12-28T08:43:48.621678Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
```

then the application tries to start up too, but then throws an exception:

```
user-management-system-app-1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused                                                       
user-management-system-app-1  |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]                                        
user-management-system-app-1  |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]                                      
user-management-system-app-1  |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547) ~[na:na]              user-management-system-app-1  |         at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602) ~[na:na]                         
user-management-system-app-1  |         at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]                       user-management-system-app-1  |         at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]                                         
user-management-system-app-1  |         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]                                                                                                                       
user-management-system-app-1  |         at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]                                                                                                                    
user-management-system-app-1  |         ... 51 common frames omitted                                                                           user-management-system-app-1  |                                                                                                                
user-management-system-app-1  | 2023-12-28T08:43:54.281Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute database script                                                                            
user-management-system-app-1  | 2023-12-28T08:43:54.294Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]                                                                                                                                   
user-management-system-app-1  | 2023-12-28T08:43:54.384Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :              user-management-system-app-1  |                                                                                                                
user-management-system-app-1  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.                                                                                                                                   
user-management-system-app-1  | 2023-12-28T08:43:54.560Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

**What's wrong?**

I guess that `depends_on` didn't help me out, as I expected. Right after

```
user-management-system-app-1 exited with code 1
```

I see

```
user-management-system-db-1   | 2023-12-28T08:44:41.307227Z 0 [System] [MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.                 
user-management-system-db-1   | 2023-12-28 08:44:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized                                      
user-management-system-db-1   | 2023-12-28 08:44:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server                                       
user-management-system-db-1   | 2023-12-28T08:44:41.440147Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
```

That is, it appears, Docker never actually waited for the MySQL server to start up, it simply waited till the container was created

With that said, if my guesses are correct, my question boils down to: **how do I delay my application start-up until a database server is fully initialized and is ready to accept connections** (though, I risk turning it into an XY problem)?

## What generative AI suggests

Poe Assistant (a generative AI chat bot) suggested downloading a `wait-for-it.sh` [script](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) (surprisingly, the link wasn't fake), putting it in the root directory, and modifying my `docker-compose.yml` file as follows:

```yaml
app:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
    - db
  entrypoint: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "java", "-jar", "user-management-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
  environment:
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/users_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: pp_user
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pp_user
```

**Is it really what I should do?** Seems a bit clumsy. As a rule, you shouldn't listen to chat bot suggestions when they suggest something like that

## What SO suggests

[This SO asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854997/23106712) sounds promising (as do other answers to that questions), but I'm not sure how I can apply it in my case. The idea is to `depend_on` health checks rather that the bare container existence. But how do I configure that health check? I don't think the MySQL image supports it out-of-the-box

```yaml
    depends_on:
      <service-name>:
        condition: service_healthy
```

The sad part is that it seems `healthcheck` dependencies are [not supported](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4305) in v. 3 because, as I understood, they now make healthchecks Docker Swarm's exclusive responsibility now. I guess, I can stay on v. 2 and somehow make it work?

> There's no reason to use the v3 format if you don't intend to use swarm services.
>
> *-- [some maintainer](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4305#issuecomment-305378202), I guess?*

> Health checks are a great use case, but again, there seems to be consensus on the fact that they are the orchestration tools' responsibility.
>
> *-- [another maintainer](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7445#issuecomment-102172168), it seems*

It *kind of* makes sense, but what do I do in small-scale environments that don't rely on any orchestration tool like Kubernetes? Developers typically don't use any orchestration tools in dev too, do they?

## What the image's doc says

> No connections until MySQL init completes
>
> If there is no database initialized when the container starts, then a default database will be created. While this is the expected behavior, this means that it will not accept incoming connections until such initialization completes. This may cause issues when using automation tools, such as docker-compose, which start several containers simultaneously.
>
> If the application you're trying to connect to MySQL does not handle MySQL downtime or waiting for MySQL to start gracefully, then **putting a connect-retry loop before the service starts might be necessary**. For an example of such an implementation in the official images, see WordPress or Bonita.
>
> *-- [the doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)*

I so much don't want to change the source code. Do I absolutely have to?

Comment: [Docker-compose check if mysql connection is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready) discusses a Compose `healthcheck:` setting that you can add to your Compose file.  You're asking Compose to start multiple containers, in a specified sequence; that is exactly the job of an orchestration tool.  It is absolutely fine to use `version: '2.4'` if you need features that aren't supported in Compose file version 3.

Comment: @DavidMaze it's ridiculous to use an orchestration tool for what is essentially a pet project

Comment: @DavidMaze by the way, I already noticed that answer and was going to post an answer here. Though it feels like a kludge