# The error [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.112.2:3306 continues to occur in docker sequelize

Tags: docker, sequelize.js

After Googling,

I found that this problem can be solved by setting the host name to the same as the service name in docker-compose.yml.

However, even if I make that correction, the same error continues to occur.

### - docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=realpassword
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - logs:/app/logs
      - ./backend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - mysql
volumes:
  data:
  logs:
```

### - sequelize index.js

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./env/mysql.env" });
const db = {};

const Goal = require("./goal");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
  {
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    host: "mysql",
    dialect: "mysql",
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
    },
  }
);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.Goal = Goal.init(sequelize);

module.exports = db;
```

### - env/mysql.env

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=test
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=realpassword
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

### - I commanded docker logs backend

```
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
80 port is ready
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.112.2:3306
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
    at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
    at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:26
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.tableExists (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:102:17)
    at async Goals.sync (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:939:21)
    at async Sequelize.sync (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:377:9) {
  parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.112.2:3306
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1602:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '192.168.112.2',
    port: 3306,
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.112.2:3306
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1602:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '192.168.112.2',
    port: 3306,
    fatal: true
  }
```

Even if I initialize the volume with docker compose down -v and restart, the same thing happens.

How should I solve this?

I've tried Googling and other searches, but the problem hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Is it possible that your application is starting up before the database is ready?  (If you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option, do you see database initialization messages after the application exits?  If you run `docker-compose up -d` twice, does it work the second time?)

Comment: You might need to add a healthcheck to your `mysql` service so your other services can wait until it's ready

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose check if mysql connection is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready)

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I used healthcheck and changed the host to host.docker.internal.

This time, that error does not occur, but this error occurs: ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Unknown database 'test'. Why does this error occur even though I run mysql first and then run the backend?