"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)", but can be started manually
I'm trying to run Docker + Flask + MySQL, and here is my docker-compose.yaml:

services:
  dockerflaskexample:
    image: dockerflaskexample
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5002:5002
    volumes:
      - app_code:/app
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    container_name: dockerflaskexample
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: webapp-db-root-password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webapp-db
      MYSQL_USER: webapp-db-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: webapp-db-password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  mysql_data:
  app_code:


... and in __init__.py:
# Establishing a connection to the MySQL database
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host='mysql',
    database='webapp-db',
    user='webapp-db-user',
    password='webapp-db-password',
    port=3306,
    charset='utf8mb4',  # adjust charset if necessary
)

After I docker-compose up, the dockerflaskexample container always fails with the following error:
2024-04-02 16:25:05 pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

However, if I simply run the Exited (3) container again, it works.
May I know why this is so? Is it because mysql isn't ready when the webapp started?

It sounds like a timing issue. MySQL needs some time to get ready to accept connections, so if you try to connect immediately, it'll refuse the connection. depends_on only waits for the database container to be started. Not for it to be ready.

This might help solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567475/docker-compose-check-if-mysql-connection-is-ready

you can add timeout in your container, moreover, you can add a health check to your database container also.
adding health check to your db coriander makes sense.

Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y also discusses this startup-order problem.

Thank you all for suggestions!
I changed my docker-compose like this and it worked:
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockerflaskexample:
    image: dockerflaskexample
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5002:5002
    volumes:
      - app_code:/app
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    container_name: dockerflaskexample
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: webapp-db-root-password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webapp-db
      MYSQL_USER: webapp-db-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: webapp-db-password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
volumes:
  mysql_data:
  app_code:

