# Mount logs of mysql container in host directory

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to mount a directory from host inside mysql container so that mysql would write its logs to that directory and I would be able to access those logs from host.

For this I am using the following volume configuration:

```
volumes:
  - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
```

But as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39710013/6207775) answer, there are permission issues between host user and container user. The solution there was to use named volumes, but what I want is to access those logs on host in a convenient directory. Not inside internal directories of docker.

Comment: You can still access them from anyone with sudo rights.

Comment: @NigelRen Problem is that mysql does not write logs to the directory unless it is given permission explicitly  to do so.

Comment: which mysql image are you using?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using `mysql:latest` image id= c73c7527c03a

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I ran the default image and made few observations

1. By default the log files are not created at all in `/var/log/mysql`. This is because the default `my.cnf` has the `error-log` settings commented
2. You need to create your own config file to add these settings and map them inside `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`
3. The `/entrypoint.sh` does change the permissions on `/var/lib/mysql` but not on `/var/log/mysql`

So to fix the issue you add a `test.cnf` file with below content

```
[mysqld]
log-error   = /var/log/mysql/error.log
general_log  = /var/log/mysql/log_output.log
```

And update your docker-compose with below settings

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log/mysql
      - ./test.cnf:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/test.cnf
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    entrypoint: ""
    command: bash -c "chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql && exec /entrypoint.sh mysqld"
```

This would make sure that before running the entrypoint script the proper permissions are set

Comment: I think this might be correct, but I cannot get it to work. If I am using a blank entrypoint, the docker-compose.yml file is invalid, and if I am removing `entrypoint` altogether, the container exits with error code 0. In second case, I think the default entrypoint is overridden due to use of `command`. I am trying to get it working, and when it does, I think this should be accepted answer :)

Comment: Not working, there were no errors and container still exits with error code 0.

Comment: Let me check. I ran using docker but solution was docker-compose based

Comment: If it helps, I am using only one services of [docoker-compose.yml](https://github.com/reactome/container/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml#L94) mysql-database and testing the code you provided on that service.

Comment: My mistake i missed adding mysqld after entrypoint.sh which is the default CMD. Check the updated answer now

Comment: Oh great! It works now. The database is up and running, but still, no logs! When I am mounting the host directory, then no logs are generated and if host directory is not mounted, then I could see logs.

Comment: Please add a note to your answer saying that user should verify if permissions have changed or not. The solution is correct, but it's just that  [Ownership remains unchanged after `sudo chown` in ubuntu](https://superuser.com/q/1237368/396312)

Comment: @Ayushya, that is not a ubuntu specific issue. I tested this on ubuntu VM only and then posted the solution. But your may be related to Windows/VM combo that you are using

Comment: It was related to NTFS filesystem. I am running ubuntu, and my project lies on different directory, which is an NTFS. Permissions on ntfs are set differently as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/113746/353904). My Uid and Gid always remained 1000

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks a lot for your help! May I ask a question? Why we need the line entrypoint: ""? Cheers

Comment: @AlbertWang, because this image uses a `entrypoint` and we want to disable that and run our own command. Docker images run the startup command as `<entrypoint command> <command>`. So you can either change the entrypoint completely to or disable it and change the command to run what we want.

Comment: @TarunLalwani db_1             | chown: cannot access '/var/log/mysql': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.

The host folder ./logs/mysql needs to be owned by UID 999 - which might cause you issues if you haven't got root access or ./logs/mysql is somewhere on a mapped drive, like NTFS or CIFS

The setting to enable **error_log** is outlined [here in the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/) - the latest versions of maria will read config files from a variety of locations and the LAST setting of this variable wins - so I've set mine in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`