DataGrip Cannot Connect to MySQL 5.7 in Dockerized Environment (Mac M1)
I was required to install MySQL 5.7 for my work on my MacBook Air 2020 M1. However, since it wasn't compatible with the architecture, I had to go through a cumbersome installation process to get Docker running. While Docker is now working, I'm facing an error with MySQL DataGrip:
DBMS: MySQL (ver. 5.7)
Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact
Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including verifying MySQL server status, checking connection details in DataGrip, addressing firewall restrictions, and considering the MySQL socket file. However, the issue persists.
Here's my Docker Compose YAML file for reference:
YAML
version: '3'
services:
  mysqlsrv:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ../.docker/mysqlMySql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - 
    build: ./
    user: root
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    depends_on:
      - mysqlsrv
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

I would be immensely grateful if anyone could assist me in resolving this issue.
I've tried several things to troubleshoot the MySQL connection error in DataGrip:
Verifying MySQL service: I checked if the MySQL server was running and accessible. I expected a successful login using the mysql command, but the result might vary depending on the specific setup.
DataGrip connection details: I ensured the hostname, port, username, and password matched the MySQL server configuration. I expected a successful connection upon saving the configuration, but it might still fail due to other reasons.
Firewall restrictions: I reviewed firewall settings to allow connections on the MySQL port (usually 3306) if applicable. I expected unrestricted access for DataGrip, but firewall rules might need adjustments.
MySQL socket file: I considered using the MySQL socket file path for the connection instead of a hostname if relevant. I expected DataGrip to connect using the socket, but the success depends on configuration.
These steps helped narrow down potential causes, but the connection error persists.

you should check the logs  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708213/enable-logging-in-docker-mysql-container

Where do you try to connect from? Is that in the same network as your container? What connection parameters do you use? What is the mysql container's name?

Are you able to telnet?

how are you trying to connect?

Your docker-compose.yml file doesn't seem to be valid. However, if the objective is simply to run MySQL in Docker and connect from an external service (DataGrip) then try this:
version: '3'
services:
  mysqlsrv:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

This will allow you to connect directly from the host machine. Presuming that you have the MySQL client installed:
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root

I don't have DataGrip but I presume that connecting should be similar to DBeaver. See screenshot below. Specify

localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the server host
root as the username and
leave the pasword field blank (since you specified MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD).


